# Blazor server game background task

Tags: signalr, blazor, backgroundworker, blazor-server-side

I am making a game with blazor server (a Monopoly-like).

I need to create a background task in order to manage some states change.

I have tried:

- Background Service
- Timer

Everything works fine but when i am deploying my project on a IIS Server or in an Azure app service, the project is stopped if no user is connected.
The project is started again when someone comes again on the game (http connection).

My questions are:

- How can i make sure IIS or Azure app service won't kill the process when no user is connected ?
- Is there a best way to do that ? Should i create a dedicated project (Console Application for example or Windows service) to manage this background process ? If so, how can i "communicate" with Blazor server project ?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a link explaining what's needed;  https://www.taithienbo.com/how-to-auto-start-and-keep-an-asp-net-core-web-application-and-keep-it-running-on-iis/   Installing the "Application Initialization" module fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks and how can i do that for Azure App Service ? Is it a good practice to create a background task in the same project ?

Comment: Why would you want a process running when no-one is connected? That seems like a terrible waste of resources. Why can you not allow the process to re-hydrate when the first user connects - and run through the state changes you missed at that point?

Comment: Let's suppose i have to start a new game every 10 minutes. And let's suppose I have to write somewhere who was connected on each game. My process have to be started everytime. And imagine someone come on the game 1 minute after the game starts.

Comment: Well there are many reasons to keep a background task running.  I've only deployed to IIS and Kubernetes, not sure about App Services.

Comment: Came here to say what Mister Magoo said (one should listen to him btw). You can keep persistent data in a database (also offered by azure). Alternatively, have a separate service to keep alive the app by doing heartbeat calls every n seconds (maybe self host that)